# How to install dotnet in Azure Pipeline for sonar scanner

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, yaml

I'm deploying a pipeline from Azure Devops to run sonar scanner for a .NET project.

Right now I have my `.yml` file in the root of the project, I have the service connection for the sonar instance with its corresponding token.

But when trying to use the task for dotnet I get this error, I don't understand what it is exactly.

```
azure-pipeline.yml
```

```
### other config ...
...
      - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
        inputs:
          SonarQube: 'azure-sonar'
          scannerMode: 'CLI'
          configMode: 'manual'
          cliProjectKey: 'prynet'
          cliProjectName: 'prynet'
          cliSources: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'  # Carpeta raíz del proyecto
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2  #this taks fail
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
```

```
Starting: DotNetCoreCLI
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.221.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'dotnet'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
Finishing: DotNetCoreCLI
```

The goal is to scan the .NET project with Sonar

Comment: Try adding the [UseDotNet@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines&source=recommendations) to acquire the specific SDK version for your build task.

Comment: It seems like that the Azure DevOps pipeline agent running the build doesn't have the dotnet command available in the PATH environment variable. Maybe fix that and try it again.

Comment: @Filburt thank u , works!!